# How to use substring to get the value after fifth space until sixth space

Tags: c#

My problem is that I want to extract the first number in a string.
The format of the string is as such

```
string text = "Board the DT line, go 1 stops toward Test";
```

What I want is the value 1. This is how I tried to do it

```
int digit1 = int.Parse(text.Substring(text.IndexOf("go")+1, text.IndexOf("stops")-1));
```

The error that I got was An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: And what issue you are facing with this code?

Comment: There is no "of" in the string. And the second parameter of Substring is the length, not the last character index.

Comment: @KlausGütter sorry it was supposed to be go but the error is still the same

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya the error was System.FormatException

Comment: What value do you get in `text.Substring(text.IndexOf("go")+1, text.IndexOf("stops")-1)` ?

Comment: The second parameter of Substring is the length, not the last character index.

Comment: "note: the first digit in a string", i thinck you want to say the first number right?

Comment: @LeBigCat i'll get it changed

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya the error is on that line, so I do not know how to check it

Comment: @KlausGütter i only need 1 digit so i removed the text.IndexOf("stops")-1 part and changed it to 1, but it still produces the same error

Comment: Assign value of `text.Substring(text.IndexOf("go")+1, text.IndexOf("stops")-1)` to some variable and use debugger to check the value of the variable. Did you try the answer mentioned below?

Comment: You forgot to add the length of "of" to skip it. So: `int digit1 = int.Parse(text.Substring(text.IndexOf("go")+3, 1));` would be correct.

Comment: The second argument of `Substring` is a **length**, not the end index. and as Klaus Gutter said, `IndexOf` is the _start_, so to get the end of the "go " string you need to add 3 more.

Comment: @KlausGütter alright it works, put it in answer, i cant checklist here or upvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are new to programming you may want to break this down into smaller tasks.

For instance you can start by hardcoding the substring values to ensure you get the correct result

```
var str = "Board the DT line, go 1 stops toward Test";   
var number = str.Substring(22, 1);
```

when you know you have the correct number you can look at how to get those values programmatically.

`var index = str.IndexOf("go "); //gives you 19`

`var index = str.IndexOf("go ") + 3 //add 3 to get the start index`

then you substitute the hard coded value for the code

`var number = str.Substring(str.IndexOf("go ") + 3, 1);`

Answer (score 0):

You could also use regex: `[0-9]+`. This pattern extracts all of the numbers in the string.

```
var matches = Regex.Matches("Board the DT line, go 1 stops toward Test", "[0-9]+");

foreach(Match match in matches)
{
    int number = int.Parse(match.Value);
    Console.WriteLine(number);
}
```

Comment: Or, if you want to be more strict, use the regex `"^Board the .*? line, go ([0-9]+) stops toward .*?$"` and extract the capture group. Heck, if the names of the stops are needed too, they can be extracted by adding two more groups for the `.*?` parts.